# Tmux: automatically run commands in the event of creating new pane or window

Tags: command-line, tmux

I have fixed `a`, `b`, `c` sessions - their name won't be changed and already auto created when I start `tmux`.

I'd like to auto run a command in the event of creating new pane or new window in a session that isn't `a` or `b` or `c`.

Comment: Do you want the command to run *in* the new pane/window, instead of the usual shell?  Or should it run in the background, *as well as* the shell that appears in the window?  It would help if you could show an example of the command you want to run, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Command run in the new pane, shell is zsh - same for new window, e.g: the event is to run ssh command to a specific host, nothing more. @JigglyNaga

Answer (score 3):

Create a simple script that's run for every new shell (eg. by calling it from your `.profile`).  It should test which Tmux session it's in (if it's in one at all) and only run the relevant command if it's in one other than `a`, `b` or `c`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$TMUX" ] ; then
        # not in tmux session
        exit
fi

TMUX_SESSION=$(tmux display-message -p '#{session_name}')

case "$TMUX_SESSION" in "a"|"b"|"c")
        exit ;;
        *)
        ssh machinename command &
esac
```

Comment: Thanks, put in .profile should work. But what about solution to re-map key that create new pane/window? - that totally won't depend on .profile.

Comment: @TuyenPham You didn't specify in the question that you needed it to be a keybinding.  Define exactly what you want the keybinding to do, and it should be straightforward to find the `tmux` command(s) to do so.